# What would someone who has seen too much of something be called? Or is there no word for this?

Tags: terminology, epithet-requests

Like when someone discovers something about their government that was suppose to be hidden & they get eliminated because they found out about it.

Comment: In addition to "liability" there is "a loose end" as well as "witness"

Answer (score 1):

A person who's **seen too much** or **knows too much** - that's the usual idiom.

The single word that comes closest is **liability**, but that's more generic and you need to put it in the right context, for instance:

"You just **know too much** about our operation, Mr Quinn. You've become a **liability**, and as much as it personally pains me, you have to be eliminated."

(That could be a cliched line from any cheesy espionage thriller).

Answer (score 1):

**Witness at risk**--See NYTimes story 'With Witnesses at Risk, Murder Suspects Go Free', March 1 2007